# Spring Security | CSRF metatags not working for internet explorer

Tags: spring, internet-explorer, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

I am using spring security 3.2.2 version in my application.
To protect csrf attack in my application I have used spring security csrf meta tags.

Here below is my code:

**Security.xml**

In security xml I have added below tag.

```
<csrf/>
```

There are two jsps. 
container.jsp and
changepassword.jsp

In **container.jsp** I added CSRF tags as below:

```
     <head>
    <sec:csrfMetaTags />
    </head>
```

Also I added changepassword.jsp in container.jsp.

```
<jsp:include
                                                page="/path/changepassword.jsp"
                                                flush="true" />
```

So I am hoping csrf metatags added in container.jsp should also applied to changepassword.jsp as container.jsp is parent page.

And changepassword.jsp is created to include in other page only so it does not contain any head tag.

Above code is working file with Chrome and mozilla,
But for internet explorer (version 11) it is not working and throwing below error,

```
exception 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parameters processing failed.
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:407)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:229)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2874)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1291)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:363)
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:180)
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:180)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:
```

I am not getting whether it is a known issue from internet explorer side or should I need to some different configuration for internet explorer?
Please assist.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The headers shouldn't be needed. I assume you are using a form, add the `csfr` needed fields to your form. See also the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-using).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for reply, This might be a solution but not targeting at actual issue of IE, Another thing there are multiple jsps that goes under container.jsp based on used case.So it not a good to edit all the jsp for csrf inbput types. to resolve issue

Comment: The tag adds a couple of headers which you can use in javascript for instance. There is no where specified in the http spec that those meta  headers need to be send back to the server. I think IE is leaving those out hence you don't get the headers.

Answer (score 0):

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=IllegalStateException%3a%20Parameters%20processing%20failed) seems to indicate this is an error in [Wildfly](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-974) / [JBoss](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP6-941). It may be triggered by the fact that one of your HTTP parameters is included twice in the request or has an empty string value.

The exact error is unlikely to be caused by Spring Security since it is simply trying to access the HTTP parameters. However, it is possible that improper setup of Spring Security is causing the Wildfly / JBoss error to occur. If this doesn't help,  you might post the HTTP request (including all the parameters) that is submitted to your application server and the application server name and version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Agree some sort of jboss issue as.But a random behavior found on last day.In debug mode I inspected the line from where it is throwing exception. For first time if I inspect i got IllegalStateException, I inspected same line second time and it work fine if after that I resuse flow (f8) then it is working fine. I am not getting why first time it is not getting parameter and second time it got the parameter. I am inspecting this line       actualToken = request.getParameter(csrfToken.getParameterName());

Comment: First, I think you probably need to find a fixed version of JBoss as this is the reason you are getting the error. Second, to figure out how this is being caused you should provide the entire HTML and JavaScript that is producing the request and the HTTP request that is causing the issue.